# How do I programatically determine how tall a div tag will be when rendered?

Tags: asp.net, sizeof

I'd like to be able to load a page up and once all the content is added see how high it is and include that as a hidden parrameter to be picked up later.  Is there a way to do this?

[NOTE] Just to clarify, I have to do this n code behind because it has to be retrieved via webrequest object.

Answer (score 2):

Sure thing. With jQuery:

```
$('#item').data('height', $('#item').height() );
```

`#item`'s height (in the box model sense, not including padding) will be stored by [$().data](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/data) as a property of itself available for later JavaScripting.

Comment: That's great except that I MUST be able to get this parameter without running scripts on the client.

Comment: Sorry to be the bearer of bad news, but there's no way to do this on the server side - there are too many variables. Some include: browser's level of CSS support, window width, browser- and platform-specific font rendering differences, fonts installed on the client's system, user stylesheets, and user scripts.